# 301 redirect with .htaccess in dynamic PHP website

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I wanted to ask you a question about 301 URL redirection. So, I have a website and it's former URL used to be:

`http://www.sample.com/tutorials.php?name=sample`

But, now it's:

`http://www.sample.com/tutorials/programming/sample.php`

So, you can conclude that the syntax of the new URL is this:

`http://www.sample.com/tutorials/(name of the category)/(value of the variable).php`

I've been toying around with 301 redirect, but I got 500 Internal server error when I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{COND ^tutorials.php?name=sample$ HTTP/1.1} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /tutorials\.php\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /tutorials/programming/%1.php [L,R=301]
```

I have also tried to create my own 301 redirect code, which gives me no 500 Internal server error, but I don't know will it work (I can't test it on localhost, because search engines don't index localhost). Here it is :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /tutorials.php?name=$1 http://www.sample.com/tutorials/programming/(.+)\.php
```

So, if my code above is good than great, but if it's not, can someone please explain (as slowly and as detailed as possible, please) how to 301 redirect my old site to my new one. As I mentioned, I use dynamic web-sites and I am rewritting using .htaccess file (mod_rewrite).

I have tried to be as detailed as possible. If you need additional details, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redirect the old links to your new domain. This is how you can do it.

**Using htaccess**:

Create a .htaccess file with the below code, it will ensure that all your directories and pages of your old domain will get correctly redirected to your new domain.
The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In addition to the redirect I would suggest that you contact every backlinking site to modify their backlink to point to your new website.

**Note:** This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.

Refer [this](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php/) for more methods

**EDIT:**

Create a .htaccess file with the below code, it will ensure that all requests coming in to domain.com will get redirected to www.domain.com
The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: OK, I added the .htaccess code you gave me. Just to ask, now all inquries to : http://www.sample.com/tutorials.php?name=something, will be redirected to : http:/www.sample.com/tutorials/programming/something.php

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! Just to ask you one more thing, can I put this : RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\.com$ before the : RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry i didn't see it properly.. I'm getting 404 when i tried [this](http://www.sample.com/tutorials/programming/something.php)..

Comment: Do you want me to post my whole .htaccess code (I just posted code snippet for my question, do youu need the whole code)?

Comment: So, with that code, I will redirect it all properly (I mean, redirect it as I mentioned in #1 comment)? Also, I capitalized some stuff, like R-s : RewriteRule and nc : NC, will code work?